# How to create a Functor for an ADT used in a cats Free Monad

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-cats, scala-3

I am writing a DSL using case classes with the help of the cats.free.Free Monad library. The DSL is to be interpreted by Actors receiving the message, so each actor has to first unwrap a command using [Free.resume](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/527bd192da9b2550387db44edac605d9791b675c/free/src/main/scala/cats/free/Free.scala#L64).

This worked out nicely six years ago using scalaz [where we also used the resume function](https://github.com/read-write-web/rww-play/blob/68ce0dac96e4a9c12c796b4e70a09a08089f087f/app/rww/ldp/actor/local/LDPRActor.scala#L315) too, but the Functor for the free monad was [easy to create](https://github.com/read-write-web/rww-play/blob/68ce0dac96e4a9c12c796b4e70a09a08089f087f/app/rww/ldp/LDPCommand.scala#L208) as we used case classes that came with an extra function argument that could be mapped over such as `k` below.

```scala
case class GetResource[Rdf <: RDF, A](
   uri: Rdf#URI,
   k: NamedResource[Rdf] => A) extends LDPCommand[Rdf, A]
```

But the current examples for cats.scala.Free [on the cats Free Monad web page](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/freemonad.html) don't come with such an argument. And indeed those work nicely when using the interpretation of Free Monads via a natural transformation. I tried this out [with a super simple DSL](https://github.com/co-operating-systems/Reactive-SoLiD/blob/f7655352984dbe6a3a0a445c7d55b210cb6f9a76/src/main/scala/run/cosy/ldp/LDPCmd.scala#L17) with only one case class

```scala
sealed trait LDPCmd[A]:
    def url: Uri

case class Get[T](url: Uri) extends LDPCmd[Response[T]]
```

For which I can then write [a simple Script](https://github.com/co-operating-systems/Reactive-SoLiD/blob/f7655352984dbe6a3a0a445c7d55b210cb6f9a76/src/main/scala/run/cosy/ldp/LDPCmd.scala#L94) which works as expected [in the tests using the natural transformation interpretation](https://github.com/co-operating-systems/Reactive-SoLiD/blob/f7655352984dbe6a3a0a445c7d55b210cb6f9a76/src/test/scala/run/cosy/ldp/TestLDPCmd.scala#L102).

But with the Actors based interpretation, I now need to unwrap each command in the free monad which gets sent around to different actors using the `resume` function of Free. This requires a Functor. But it is not clear to me where the functor can get a hold. Ie, what do I put in the ??? position here

```scala
given CmdFunctor: cats.Functor[LDPCmd] with 
    def map[A, B](fa: LDPCmd[A])(f: A => B): LDPCmd[B] = fa match 
        case g: Get => ???
```

Comment: Added the Scala 3 tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is it seems to return back to adding the extra function to the case class. On the cats chat channel Rob Norris wrote:

> The classical encoding of Free[F, *] is a monad only if F is a functor, so you needed the extra Blah => A member for each case. Then we figured out that you could use Free[Coyoneda[F, *], *] and get that machinery for free. Then we figured out how to just bake it into Free, so you don’t need to do any of that most of the time.
> But if you need to walk through your computation step by step you do need one of those encodings because F still needs to be a Functor in that case.

The code he pointed to is [SimMessageSocket.scala](https://github.com/tpolecat/skunk/blob/d7efc99a24a989f2e9a2659b5a41c66ea0ea7712/modules/tests/src/test/scala/simulation/SimMessageSocket.scala#L27).

```scala
sealed trait Step[+A]
  case class Send[A](m: BackendMessage, k: Unit => A) extends Step[A]
  case class Expect[A](h: PartialFunction[FrontendMessage, A]) extends Step[A]
  object Step {
    implicit val FunctorStep: Functor[Step] =
      new Functor[Step] {
        def map[A,B](fa: Step[A])(f: A => B): Step[B] =
          fa match {
            case Send(m, k) => Send(m, k andThen f)
            case Expect(h)    => Expect(h andThen f)
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your data type: `Get[T]` does not use `T`, so cannot map this meaningfully, other than a no-op: `g: Get => Get[B](g)`

Comment: Why is that a problem? The Functor laws hold, so that's a perfectly good Functor. It's actually so useful that cats includes a generalized version of that same datatype: Const.
https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/const.html

Comment: yes, but I don't want a const functor :-) I want to use it to build a script that fetched some data at a location, as in the [example function I gave](https://github.com/co-operating-systems/Reactive-SoLiD/blob/f7655352984dbe6a3a0a445c7d55b210cb6f9a76/src/main/scala/run/cosy/ldp/LDPCmd.scala#L94). It works with the natural transformations method of interpretation, but I need to build one that use the functor.

Comment: Perhaps I just have to add that extra argument back...